# Proper way to zero a AnsiString object

Tags: c++builder-6, ansistring

How do we zero a AnsiString object? For example:

```
void TesteClass::test()
{
    AnsiString cardNumber = "1234567890123456";
    ..
}
```

The AnsiString object is destroyed automatically, but its internal data is not cleaned, so a memory acquisition tool can read the information. We need to zero this data to avoid sensitive information be captured in memory.

The AnsiString class has the method `c_str()` to access the internal data directly, but doing some like this is not recommended:

```
memset(cardNumber.c_str(), 0, cardNumber.Length());
```

What is the correct way to zero the AnsiString internal data before the object is destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `memset()` like you have shown. Using `c_str()` in this manner is correct (as long as you do not exceed the `Length()`, since `c_str()` returns a pointer to const memory if the `AnsiString` is blank):

```
void TesteClass::test()
{
    AnsiString cardNumber = "1234567890123456";
    // ...
    memset(cardNumber.c_str(), 0, cardNumber.Length());
}
```

Since you are worried about information leakage, consider using [`SecureZeroMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877.aspx) instead of `memset()` (see [What’s the point of SecureZeroMemory?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130529-00/?p=4223)).

To automate the zeroing (so you don't have to remember to do it), consider wrapping the `AnsiString` inside an RAII-style `class`/`struct` (you cannot derive from `AnsiString` directly, the RTL does not allow it), whose destructor performs the zeroing, and then use that `class`/`struct` where needed instead of using `AnsiString` directly.

Just be careful, since `AnsiString` uses reference-counted data, so don't zero the data unless your `AnsiString` is the sole instance referencing the data:

```
class SaferAnsiString
{
private:
    AnsiString m_Str;

    void CheckZeroNeeded()
    {
        // AnsiString gained a public RefCount() method in C++Builder 2009.
        // In earlier versions, access the reference count manually...
        #ifdef _DELPHI_STRING_UNICODE
        if (m_Str.RefCount() == 1)
        #else
        const void *data = m_Str.data();
        if ((data) && (static_cast<const int*>(data)[-2] == 1))
        #endif
            SecureZeroMemory(m_Str.c_str(), m_Str.Length());
    }

public:
    SaferAnsiString(const AnsiString &src = AnsiString())
        : m_Str(src)
    {
    }

    ~SaferAnsiString()
    {
        CheckZeroNeeded();
    }

    SaferAnsiString& operator=(const AnsiString &rhs)
    {
        CheckZeroNeeded();
        m_Str = rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    operator AnsiString () const { return m_Str; }

    // other methods as needed...
};
```

```
void TesteClass::test()
{
    SaferAnsiString cardNumber = "1234567890123456";
    // ...
}
```